# QuerySyntaxException no mapping

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am using JPQL . I want to use a Name Queryparameter inside my query. But I get this exception.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: testcases is not mapped [SELECT TC FROM testcases TC ]
```

This is my query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT TC FROM testcases TC ")
List<TestcaseEntity> filterHMI(@Param("testcases") List<TestcaseEntity> lstTestcases);
```

Comment: Your entity is apparently named `TestcaseEntity`, not `testcases`. So querying from `testcases` is incorrect. This is a JPQL query, not a SQL query. Those are two different languages. JPQL uses entity names, not table names.

Comment: so how can I use testcases . How would the query look? It's passed as a parameter and it is definitely possible to use parameters in your query

Comment: Your query has no parameter at all. You're ignoring the list of test cases passed as argument. The problem is `FROM testcases TC`. `testcases` is not the name of an entity. The entity is named `TestcaseEntity`. So it must be `FROM TestcaseEntity`.

Comment: of course I have a param  which is   annotated with @Param("testcases")  look:                                                                 List<TestcaseEntity> filterHMI(  @Param("testcases") List<TestcaseEntity> lstTestcases);

Comment: But you're not doing anything with that parameter in the query. And, again, this has nothing to do with the error you get. The error you get is caused by the fact that you're trying to select from `testcases`, and `testcases` is not an entity.

Comment: so if I write @Query(value = "SELECT TC FROM TestcaseEntity TC ") I will use passed testcases ???

Comment: No. You will fix the exception you're asking about. To use the passed test cases, you need to use it as a parameter in the query. But I have no idea of what this query is supposed to do, because you didn't tell.

Comment: It should simply select all passed teestcases. In native sql it would look :  Select * from testcases . How would that look in JPQL?

Comment: No. Not at all. That, in native SQL, would select all the rows from the table testcases. Which is equivalent to the JPQL `select TC from TestcaseEntity TC`, which select all the instances of TestCaseEntity stored in the database, i.e. all the rows of the table testcases. If you want to select all the test cases that are in the table, and also in the passed list (but why, since you already have them?), you'd need `select TC from TestCaseEntity TC where TC in :testcases`

Comment: aha. ok . I really only need the passed testcases, not all in database, because I will filter them again.

Comment: Well, read m previous comment.

Comment: ok. that helps me definitely. It looks like you only can use passed parameters with clause IN

Comment: No, of course not. Why would you only be able to use parammeters in an `in` clause? You can use a parameter wherever you have a value in a query (but of course the query must make sense).

Comment: yes but as you said before I already have the list of testcases I will need but still I have to get all testcases TestcaseEntity TC and check if these are IN testcases

Comment: No, that's not what I said. I said that the query `select TC from TestCaseEntity TC where TC in :testcases` will query, from the database table, the test cases that are also in (i.e. are elements of) the list passed as parameter. That loo,ks quite awkward to me, but as far as I understood, that's what you want.

Comment: yes exactly !!! . But hopefully it will not go the database , get all testcases there and then check which are IN my testcases List I passed as parameter, that would be really a waste of time, but it seems that is the syntax how I can use my passed testcases

Comment: Of course it will go to the database. That's the whole point of a database query: to query the database. Why would you use a query to return all the elements of a list in memory. You already have the list. So just use it.

Comment: the thing is I want to use pagination and that only works wiith queries from repository

Comment: Ah, so that's what your problem actually is? You have a list in memory, and you ant to return a page out of it? Then you don't need JPA, you don't need a query, you don't need any of that. All you need is arithmetics, and the subList() method. If you have a list of 123 test cases and someone asks for the second page of 10 cases, you really should be able to figure how to get the appropriate sublist by yourself.

Comment: ok that is right pretty easy. I am still learning. The reason why I had to pass these list of testcases was because I am too stupid to make it in just one query. I asked a question in a different link which nobody answered so far, but that was my original problem. Here is the link . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723211/jpql-query-not-working-after-needed-to-adapt-it

Comment: did you look at the link. Do you think there is a way to write only 1 query in JPQL instead of write 1 query get List of testcases and then manually again filter these by myself which is kind of inconvenient

Comment: I had a quick look. But honestly, the question was extreamly unclear to me (just as this one)

Comment: hm ok. But thanks for your help so far. At least I will be able to solve the problem. Even though maybe it is not the best solution

Comment: I think I could only solve my previous problem with a subselect in the FROM clause. But subselect in JPQL is only allowed after where clause and not allowed after select or from clause. Could you imagine or do you know why there is this restriction on subselect in JPQL ?